# Symfony: createForm(), Type __construct($arg). Передать аргумент в конструктор

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony, symfony3

Можно ли передать аргумент в конструктор класса Type для создания формы?
Для примера:

TestType

```
public $arg;

public function __construct($arg)
{
    $this->arg = $arg;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'arg'=> null,
    ));
}
```

TestController

```
$form = $this->createForm(TestType::class, $test, ['arg'=>'test']);
```

Или надо убрать конструктор и делать все в методе buildForm()?

```
//TestType.php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->arg = $options['arg'];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Для этого достаточно зарегистрировать TestType в сервис контейнере, внедрить нужные зависимости (в нашем случае аргумент конструктора) и присвоить полученному сервису тэг `form.type`.

```yaml
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    app.form.type.test:
        class: AppBundle\Form\TestType
        arguments: ['Я аргумент конструктора']
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

При этом код контроллера не требует изменений:

```php
$form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $test);
```

Экземпляры класса TestType будут созданы с передачей описанных в сервисе аргументов конструктора (в данном случае это строка 'Я аргумент конструктора'.

```php
class TestType extends AbstractType
{   
    public function __construct($argument)
    {
        print_r($argument);
    }
}
```

*Важно: Сервис должен быть публичным.*

Аргументами сервиса могут быть также параметры контейнера ('%my_parameter%') или другие сервисы ('@my_service').

Примеры в [документации](http://symfony.com/doc/3.1/form/form_dependencies.html#define-your-form-as-a-service)

#### Как это работает:

Достаточно упрощенно схему работы можно представить следующим образом:

- На этапе компиляции контейнера фреймворк соберет все сервисы отмеченные тегом form.type и сформирует из них карту соответствия класс -> сервис:

  ```
  // [TestType::class => 'app.form.type.test']
  $types[$serviceDefinition->getClass()] = $serviceId;
  ```
- Когда потребуется создать экземпляр класса `TestType::class`, описанная выше карта будет использована для ленивого получения экземпляра формы из сервис контейнера со всеми внедренными зависимостями. Цепочка делегируемых вызовов при этом выглядит следующим образом:

  `FormBuilder -> FormRegistry -> FormExtension[]`